# Showposts doesn't show the number of posts indicated

Tags: loop

on my homepage, I'm using several loops to display posts from different categories in various sections of the page.

The code I'm adding before the loop is :

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=featured&showposts=5'); ?>
```

The loop comes just afterwards

```
<?php 

        if ( have_posts() ) : 
        /* Start the Loop */
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            get_template_part( $layout, 'blog-'.get_post_format() );
            endwhile;
        else :
?>

        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found clearfix">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'swift' ); ?></h1>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but there are no posts in the current context. Perhaps searching will help find a related 

post.', 'swift' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </article><!-- #post-0 -->
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

And I copy paste this with the desired categories. Problem is eventhough I mention shoposts=5, 10 posts show up, whatever number I indicate.

Do you guys have any clues please ?

Thanks

Comment: do you have sticky posts? are the 5 extra posts always the same? for multiple loops, also read http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts

Answer (score 0):

I believe the right parameter would be numberposts

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=featured&numberposts=5'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Actually I tried that too, but that didn't work. But I tried with that code : `<?php $custom_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=5&cat=137');. As explained on this page http://digwp.com/2011/05/loops/